# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token on regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to remove a parameter from url with regexp and i keep getting  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

```
    var url=window.location.href;

    //Remove p first
    url = url.replace(/p/([0-9]+)/, '');
```

i am trying to remove the p parapemeter /p/*

my testing url is 
http://mycompany.com/en/category/p/5

What am i doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: You need to quote the slash: `/p\/([0-9]+)/`

Answer (score 1):

Apart of prepending the `/` with a backslash (as it was stated in a comment to
your post), another hint: As you want **only** to delete the matched string,
the capturing group here is not needed.

So change your code to:

```
url = url.replace(/p\/[0-9]+/, '');
```

Or even shorter option:

```
url = url.replace(/p\/\d+/, '');
```